# Java - How to add an mouse event to TrayIcon.displayMessage()?

Tags: java, mouse, trayicon

I have an app that use TrayIcon and I'm showing a message (like a balloon message) using the method `displayMessage()`.

It's like:

```
tray.displayMessage("My Title", "My Message", TrayIcon.MessageType.WARNING);
```

Where `tray` is my `TrayIcon` object.

But when I click this "balloon" nothing happens. To be since, the balloon is closed, but I want to make something when I click this balloon.
How do I add an mouse event on this message?

If it's not possible, anyone have any good idea that i can use to solve my problem?